# Magento - Mailgun plugin not sending email

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9, mailgun

I'm using `Magento` v1.9.1, with a `MailGun` plugin installed.

Plugin url:
https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/mailgun-for-email-delivery.html

Here you can see the `MailGun` plugin on the admin area:

[image]

Then I used the following code to send a test email (`test_email.php`):

```
<?php
// Invoke the Magento environment
require_once( 'app/Mage.php' );
Mage::app();

//Getting the Store E-Mail Sender Name.
$senderName = Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/name');

//Getting the Store General E-Mail.
$senderEmail = Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/email');

$customerEmail = "<personal_email@hidden_on_purpose>";
$text = "Hello, this is a test.";

//Sending E-Mail to Customers.
$mail = Mage::getModel('core/email')
 ->setToName($senderName)
 ->setToEmail($customerEmail)
 ->setBody($text)
 ->setSubject('Subject :')
 ->setFromEmail($senderEmail)
 ->setFromName($senderName)
 ->setType('html');
 try{
 //Confimation E-Mail Send
 $mail->send();
 }
 catch(Exception $error)
 {
 Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError($error->getMessage());
 return false;
 }
?>
```

Then the email arrives to me but it is not sent via MailGun. I know that because on the header of the received email is the server where the application lives and on the MailGun log the email is not logged.

I think the MailGun plugin is working on the backend admin area only, but it is not getting called when sending an email with Magento.

I also did a test modifying the file:

> ./app/code/community/FreeLunchLabs/MailGun/Model/Mailgun.php
>   by adding the line:

```
die("Send stopped on file: ./app/code/community/FreeLunchLabs/MailGun/Model/Mailgun.php");
```

Like:

```
...
    public function send($message) {

        die("Send stopped on file: ./app/code/community/FreeLunchLabs/MailGun/Model/Mailgun.php");

        $domain = $message->getStore()->getConfig('mailgun/general/domain');
        $apiKey = $message->getStore()->getConfig('mailgun/general/key');
        $files = null;

        if(count($message->getAttachments())) {
            foreach($message->getAttachments() as $attachment) {
                $files[] = $attachment;
            }
        }

        $sendResponse = $this->mailgunRequest('messages', $domain, $apiKey, $message->getMessage(), Zend_Http_Client::POST, false, $files);

        if($message->getStore()->getConfig('mailgun/events/store')) {
            Mage::getModel('freelunchlabs_mailgun/email')->saveInitialSend($message, $sendResponse);
        }

        return $sendResponse;
    }

...
```

But when running the file: `test_email.php`, the `stopped message` inside the `die(...)` on the code above doesn't appear.

Any idea on how to solve/debug this?

Comment: In the same circumstance as above (but removing the line of: "die" inside: "send"), I tested the email system with formal emails of Magento, like the subscription and create an account and on those cases the emails were sent via Mailgun correctly. But when I send a custom email with the first code: "test_email.php", then the email is not sent via MailGun, but through the default smtp relay. Any idea on how to use MailGun also in custom emails?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after some try/error experiments I found the answer: that `MailGun` extension applies only to `transactional emails` as stated on its description. You cannot send custom emails using `MailGun` straightforward like on my initial code: `test_email.php`. If you wanna send some custom email using `MailGun` you should create a template before and then use that template like in the following code where I created the template with id: 1

```
<?php
// Invoke the Magento environment
require_once( 'app/Mage.php' );
Mage::app();

$templateId = 1;
$receiveName  = "<Your Name Here>";
$receiveEmail = "<your email here>";

$storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId();

$emailTemplate = Mage::getModel("core/email_template")->load($templateId);

$vars = array(
        "name"      => $receiveName,
        "email"     => $receiveEmail,
        "phone"     => "+13052491037",
        "comment"   => "This is my comment: Hello World!"
);

$emailTemplate->getProcessedTemplate($vars);

/*
echo "<pre>\n";
print_r($emailTemplate);
echo "</pre>\n";
die();
//*/

$emailTemplate->setSenderName(Mage::getStoreConfig("trans_email/ident_general/name", $storeId));
$emailTemplate->setSenderEmail(Mage::getStoreConfig("trans_email/ident_general/email", $storeId));

$emailTemplate->send($receiveEmail, $receiveName, $vars);

?>
```

Hope this helps somebody.